# Is it bad practice to use a C header instead of its C++ equivalent in C++ (e.g. stdio.h instead of cstdio)?

Tags: c++, header-files

It seems that a lot of people include example.h instead of cexample in their C++ code. I know that everything in the C++ versions is declared in namespace std, but I'm not aware of any other differences. So why do people use the C headers, and is it okay to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the two is that the C headers that C++ imported (by prefixing with c and removing the .h suffix) are in namespace `std`. This so any call or use of a standard facility is prefixed with `std::`, for uniformity. It's [The Standard Way Of Doing Things(tm)](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.2). Unless of course you already have a bunch of C code in which you don't feel like appending `std::` to each standard call: then use the classic C headers.

Comment: Actually, for all implementations I'm aware of, including the C++ headers puts the names in both the std and the global namespace.

Comment: "Unless of course you already have a bunch of C code in which you don't feel like appending std:: to each standard call". Even for that case, C++ has a solution: Using declaration and directives.

Comment: what i meant is that you take a bunch of C code and compile it with a C++ compiler. if that's the only issue then there's no need to change anything. but in all but the simplest cases you'd probably get many more compile errors than using standard c functions without `std::`.

Answer (score 2):

For example `stdio.h` is not the same as `cstdio`. The latter includes the first, but then undefines some macros and replaces them with real functions. Personally I would always go with the C++ headers!

Comment: Oh, it does? I wasn't aware. That seems like a pretty compelling reason.

Comment: That's an implementation specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK. But it somehow seems neater to to use the C++ style (i.e. no .h extension) in C++ code. I wouldn't (and I don't) worry about it.

Comment: I agree, which is the main reason I'd been using C++ style.

Comment: I disagree. Because you still have to say `#include "myheader.h"`, thus ending up needing the extension anyways.

Answer (score 1):

when working with C++, I prefer to use C++ header syntax unless there's a reason not to.  It also appears to be safer to use the `<name>` (with no `.h` syntax) based on the following comments in the standard:

Section 17.4.1.2, paragraphs 3 and 4 (ISO/IEC 14882, Second edition 2003-10-15) state:

> The facilities of the Standard C Library are provided in 18 additional headers, as shown in Table 12:

It then lists off the table, e.g. `<cassert>`, `<ciso646>`, ... and then continues

> Except as noted in clauses 18 through 27, the contents of each header *cname* shall be the same as that of the corresponding header *name*.h....

Thus, the standard defines the headers without the `.h` but does indicate that, for the most part, they are identical to those provided by the C compiler and provides clauses 18-27 to identify the differences.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out where those sections are in the standard to be able to document the differences should they be useful.

<del>I don't believe there is a requirement that the `.h` headers be present when using a C++ compiler.</del>

As @James pointed out in a comment, Section D.5, paragraphs 1 and 2 state that the C headers must be present:

> ... the C++ Standard library provides the 18 C *headers*....
>
> Every C header, each of which has a name of the form *name*.h behaves as if each name placed in the Standard library namespace by the corresponding *cname* header is also placed within the namespace scope of the namespace `std` and is followed by an explicit *using-declaration* (7.3.3)

Comment: Well, as you obviously "know the difference", what is it?

Comment: @Neil It sounds to me like he means that you should use the C++ versions of things if you're using C++ unless you have a reason not to. Still, it's good to know the difference.

Comment: @Jonathan - Yes, that's what I thought I said, although I'll admit I get frustrated on this topic (more especially with the C++ headers `iostream` vs `iostream.h` and programmers not knowing that only the former is defined by even not-so-recent versions of the standard, etc.) Sorry if I was too opinion-oriented.

Comment: I can't imagine the .h headers are not required because removing it would break compatibility with legacy C code.

Comment: A C++ standard library implementation _is_ required to include the C standard library headers (the `name.h` headers).  The requirement is in D.5/1 in the C++ standard.

Comment: @Neil - In looking back at my original statement, it had very poor tone and definitely didn't say what I intended. You were very restrained to not downvote me. My apologies.