# c++ getchar works in vs 2010, doesn't in 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Why the program just exits, in vs 2012, while in 2010 does it wait for my input?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string path = "c:\somepath";
    cout << "Path is" + path << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to remove the `endl` and replace it by `\n` , i think this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8443105/3871352

Comment: @Kiloreux and how would that help??

Comment: removing endl and adding \n didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The `getchar()` function is not used in the program flow and only the side effect of waiting for input is used in your case. Instead of hacking your program to avoid closing the window you should use the proper way  to keep it open.

Choose one of:

1. Command window

   - open a command prompt
   - navigate to the folder where you want your program to execute
   - type the path to the .exe and hit Enter. The command prompt is still open after execition of your program and there is not need for `getchar()`.
2. Start without debugging

   - just use the menu item Debug->Start Without Debugging. The new console window is still open after execition of your program and there is not need for `getchar()`.
3. Start with debugging

   - Set a breakpoint at the closing '}' of your main function.
   - use the menu item Debug->Start. The debugging session is still active and the window for your console program is still open. There is not need for `getchar()`.

Why you should avoid `getchar()` to keep a window open?

- It's a hack that depends on the program before. There can be some characters in the input buffer a s pointer out here: [getchar() doesn't work well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442644/getchar-doesnt-work-well/8443105#8443105)
- Your program can't be used in batch file if you come beyond the phase where you try to learn C or C++.
- It's not necessary.